# Hive creating delta folder and bucket files

Tags: hive, hiveql

Below is my hive insert query to copy data from one table to another

```
INSERT INTO target_table PARTITION(eventdate) SELECT col1,col2,.... FROM source_table ;
```

Target table is empty initially.My assumption was,while copying the data HIVE would create single file under each partition, however my directory structure looks like below

```
hdfs dfs -ls /warehouse/tablespace/managed/hive/test.db/target_table/eventdate=2019-04-28/delta_0000001_0000001_0000
-rwxrwxrwx+  3 hive hadoop          1 2019-05-08 09:54 hdfs://SugarBOXNNHA/warehouse/tablespace/managed/hive/test.db/target_table/eventdate=2019-04-28/delta_0000001_0000001_0000/_orc_acid_version
-rwxrwxrwx+  3 hive hadoop       6071 2019-05-08 09:54 hdfs://SugarBOXNNHA/warehouse/tablespace/managed/hive/test.db/target_table/eventdate=2019-04-28/delta_0000001_0000001_0000/bucket_00002
-rwxrwxrwx+  3 hive hadoop       5194 2019-05-08 09:54 hdfs://SugarBOXNNHA/warehouse/tablespace/managed/hive/test.db/target_table/eventdate=2019-04-28/delta_0000001_0000001_0000/bucket_00007
-rwxrwxrwx+  3 hive hadoop       6606 2019-05-08 09:54 hdfs://SugarBOXNNHA/warehouse/tablespace/managed/hive/test.db/target_table/eventdate=2019-04-28/delta_0000001_0000001_0000/bucket_00008
```

**Table definitions:**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS source_table 
(col1 string, col2 string, col3 string,eventdate date) 
PARTITIONED BY (loaddate STRING) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
STORED AS ORC LOCATION '/warehouse/ext_hive_tables/source_table/data';

CREATE TABLE target_table(col1 string, col2 string, col3 string)  
PARTITIONED BY ( eventdate date) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' STORED AS ORC;
```

Why does hive create 'delta_0000001_0000001_0000' folder and multiple files with name 'bucket_*' under that folder? I have not applied bucketing in my table. Is there any way to copy everything in single file under partition folder

Comment: please add table definition, source and target

Comment: Table definition updated